# How to generate fake data that looks real in a graph

Tags: javascript, random, highcharts

I want to generate fake data for use in testing a graphing library (highcharts in this case, but it doesn't really matter).  I'd like to generate random data on each click that looks like it might actually be real data in a line chart, for example.

What that means to me is that the naive approach of just a series of (X+1, rand()) doesn't work.  It wouldn't fool anyone most of the time.

Are there approaches that will look like "real data" but can be generated over and over to produce different shapes that look "real".  Sorry for being vague, it's sort of a "I know it when I see it" kind of thing.

What I'm looking for is an algorithm, not a particular language implementation.  Ruby and/or javascript is what I'd be using most likely, though.

Comment: Here's a link (sorry not sure how long it lasts) to a graph I generated with midpoint displacement:  http://imgur.com/L70qp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Midpoint Displacement like its described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170812230846/http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html#midpoint)

In this algorithm you start with a few random points and then compute small height offsets between these points.

Its often used for 2D Terrain generation in computer games.

Answer (score 2):

How about a slightly noisy line, like this?

`perl -e '$slope = rand()*3; print "$_, ", $slope*$_ + (rand() - .5)*$slope, "\n" foreach 0 .. 9;'`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case (i.e. for graphs with trends that are **visually** recognizable), you should

1. decide what your graph is intended to look like i.e. the function
   for your graph without the noise in the data.
2. decide what type of noise you wish to add to your data (in layman's
   term what is the randomness going to be like) i.e. your noise model
   (uniform, gaussian etc.).
3. For each randomly (or deliberately chosen point), add noise sampled
   from your noise model to it.

E.g. if you wish your curve to look like a straight line, your function is y = f(x) = mx + c with uniform noise, between interval 0 <= x < 100 (or any interval you like), you

1. pick m and c first, the slope of your line and y-intercept. You could of course randomly select m and c from a range of values. E.g. if you want a <= m < b where a, b are 2 arbitrary numbers you picked:

   int m = a + (rand() % (b - a));
2. Randomly pick N number of points in your x interval i.e. call rand() %
   100 N number of times to get your N number of x values within the interval 0 <= x < 100.
3. For each of the x value say xi, you have a corresponding y value yi = f(xi)
   by substituting xi into your equation for your line.
4. Now add noise to your yi using your noise model. This step is specific to
   the noise model you picked. Lets say you are using uniform noise
   (the easiest) within the interval -1 to 1 (this is specific to your
   choosing). All you need to do is again call

   int noise = (rand() % 3) - 1;  // Noise between -1 to 1. Rand() is an approximate for uniform noise.

   yi = yi + noise;
5. Your random data point is thus (xi, yi).

A lot of things here is customizable. You can of course

1. use a different function other than that for a line e.g. y = f(x) =
   sinx etc.
2. use a different noise model e.g. Gaussian to change the "look" of
   the noise in your graph.
3. pick different intervals for x and for the range of your noise.
4. Pick different parameters for your graph's equation. E.g. in our
   line e.g., you can pick m and c.

Hope this helps.